# Failed to group resized columns on Excel with openpyxl got traceback on DimensionHolder.group

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm forging an Excel file with `openpyxl`.

I set specific size for the 3 first columns 'A', 'B' and 'B', and I try then to group/fold column 'B' and 'C'.

With the sample code below I get this Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python_excel.py", line 64, in <module>
    wb, ws = set_col_width(wb, ws)
  File "python_excel.py", line 56, in set_col_width
    dim_holder.group("B", "C", hidden=True)
  File "/.../site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/dimensions.py", line 208, in group
    if isinstance(self.default_factory(), ColumnDimension):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

When I don't resize the A, B, C columns group work well

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import column_index_from_string
from openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions import ColumnDimension, DimensionHolder
import pandas as pd


def mk_xlsx():
    "Forge some data"
    df_raw = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "animal": "cat dog cat fish dog cat cat".split(),
            "mysize": list("SSMMMLL"),
            "weight": [8, 10, 11, 1, 20, 12, 12],
        }
    )
    print(df_raw)
    #   animal mysize  weight
    # 0    cat      S       8
    # 1    dog      S      10

    df_raw.to_excel("/tmp/a.xlsx", sheet_name="raw", header=True, index=False)
    book = load_workbook("/tmp/a.xlsx", read_only=False)
    sheet = book.active
    assert sheet["A2"].value == "cat"
    return book, sheet


def set_col_width(book, sheet):
    "Simple set columns width and group example"
    dim_holder = DimensionHolder(worksheet=sheet)
    for col_name, width in [("A", 15), ("B", 60), ("C", 30)]:
        col_num = column_index_from_string(col_name)
        col_dim = ColumnDimension(sheet, width=width, min=col_num, max=col_num)
        dim_holder[col_name] = col_dim
    # Group columns
    dim_holder.group("B", "C", hidden=True)  # <= here my traceback
    sheet.column_dimensions = dim_holder
    return book, sheet


if __name__ == "__main__":
    wb, ws = mk_xlsx()
    wb, ws = set_col_width(wb, ws)
    wb.save(filename="/tmp/b.xlsx")
    print("file saved")
```

If I remove the line `dim_holder.group("B", "C", hidden=True)` from `def set_col_width` method and replace it by a direct call to the ws.column_dimensions.group method:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    wb, ws = mk_xlsx()
    wb, ws = set_col_width(wb, ws)

    ws.column_dimensions.group("B", "C", hidden=True)  # <= this

    wb.save(filename="/tmp/b.xlsx")
    print("file saved")
```

I get this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python_excel.py", line 82, in <module>
    ws.column_dimensions.group("B", "C", hidden=True)  # <= this
  File "/home/luis/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/dimensions.py", line 208, in group
    if isinstance(self.default_factory(), ColumnDimension):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: This looks excessively complex but the exception makes it clear that you have the columnd dimensions to None.

Comment: yes but it should not, here  `ws.column_dimensions.group`  the documented API is used to group columns. The "complexity" is to provide a self-sustained and reproducible piece of code

Comment: Well, it's your code that isn't working. https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/blob/branch/3.0/openpyxl/worksheet/tests/test_dimensions.py#L170 shows that the openpyxl code works.

Comment: Have you any clue of what is causing the Traceback ?